# getting when running tkinter file NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "C:\Users\mouad\Desktop\Project 2\tkinter.py", line 11, in <module>
    mainwindow = Tk()
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

and when using python directly by running in cmd python I got no issue importing

Answer (score 0):

It is not written like that, i advise you to do this :

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

If i dont work chek if tkinter is well installed.

Comment: the problem was the name of the file.i was naming it tkinter as well and that made the error .